# How to create a simple cache using RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I would like to create a cache srvice using RxJs. Idea is simple, I have a class that will fetch some data from server initialy and a websocket that will push notification to this service (add / edit / delete of entity).

The following code is a simplification to make me anderstand how to achieve what I need.

```html
const source = of(['World', 'test', 'azerty', 'uiop']);
const add$ = new Subject<string>();
const update$ = new Subject<string>();
const delete$ = new Subject<string>();
```

So, the real question is: How can I create an high order observable that will react on any update from add$, update$ and delete$ ?

I would like to have one variable 'cache$' that is an observable composed from source, add update and delete. And initialy filled from data streamed by source (that will be an http call observable).

Comment: You can use `merge` https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found a solution

```js
import { combineLatest, Observable, of, Subject } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface ITestPayload {
  id: number,
  name?: string,
}

interface ICacheEvent {
  eventType: 'INIT' | 'ADD' | 'EDIT' | 'DELETE',
  payload: ITestPayload,
}

const source: Observable<Array<ITestPayload>> = of([{id: 1, name: 'World'}, {id: 2, name: 'test'}, {id: 3, name: 'azerty'}]);
const event$ = new Subject<ICacheEvent>();

let cache$ = combineLatest([
  source,
  event$.pipe(startWith({eventType: 'INIT', payload: null})),
]).pipe(
  map(([source, event]) => {
  if (event.eventType === 'ADD'){
      const index = source.map(x => x.id).indexOf(event.payload.id);

      if(index === -1) {
        source.push(event.payload);
      }
    }
    else if (event.eventType === 'DELETE'){
      const index = source.map(x => x.id).indexOf(event.payload.id);

      if(index >= 0) {
        source.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
    else if (event.eventType === 'EDIT'){
      const index = source.map(x => x.id).indexOf(event.payload.id);

      if(index >= 0) {
        source[index] = event.payload;
      }
    }

    return source;
  })
)

cache$.subscribe(x => console.log(x.map(item => item.name)));

event$.next({eventType: "ADD", payload: {id: 4, name: 'test 4'}})
event$.next({eventType: "EDIT", payload: {id: 2, name: 'value edited'}});
event$.next({eventType: "DELETE", payload: {id: 1}});
```

Another solution (proposed by one of my colleague)

```js
import { combineLatest, merge,  Observable, of, Subject } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, scan,  shareReplay,  startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface ITestPayload {
  id: number,
  name?: string,
}

interface ICacheEvent {
  eventType: 'INIT' | 'ADD' | 'EDIT' | 'DELETE',
  payload: ITestPayload,
}

const source: Observable<Array<ITestPayload>> = of([{id: 1, name: 'World'}, {id: 2, name: 'test'}, {id: 3, name: 'azerty'}]);
const eventSubject$ = new Subject<ICacheEvent>();
const event$ = eventSubject$.asObservable();

const cache$: Observable<Array<ITestPayload>> = merge(
  source,
  event$,
).pipe(
  scan((acc: ITestPayload[], value: ICacheEvent) => {
    console.log('scan');
    if (value.eventType === 'ADD'){
      const index = acc.map(x => x.id).indexOf(value.payload.id);

      if(index === -1) {
        acc.push(value.payload);
      }
    }
    else if (value.eventType === 'DELETE'){
      const index = acc.map(x => x.id).indexOf(value.payload.id);

      if(index >= 0) {
        acc.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
    else if (value.eventType === 'EDIT'){
      const index = acc.map(x => x.id).indexOf(value.payload.id);

      if(index >= 0) {
        acc[index] = value.payload;
      }
    }

    return acc;
  }))

cache$.subscribe(x => console.log('sub 0 :', x.map(item => item.name)));

eventSubject$.next({eventType: "ADD", payload: {id: 4, name: 'test 4'}})
eventSubject$.next({eventType: "EDIT", payload: {id: 2, name: 'value edited'}});
eventSubject$.next({eventType: "DELETE", payload: {id: 1}});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like here

```
const update$ = merge([
  add$.pipe(map(addItem => items => items.concat([addItem]))),
  delete$.pipe(map(deleteItem => items => items.filter(item => item !== addItem))),
  update$.pipe(map(updateItem => items => items.map(item => /* not very clear how exactly you want to update */))),
])
const cache$ = source.pipe(
  switchMap((startItems) => update$.pipe(scan((prevItems, changerFn) => changerFn(prevItems), startItems))),
  publish(),
);
cache$.connect();
```